# how to change bootstrap carousel arrow class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this bootstrap carousel with arrows at the top right corner. I have set `data-wrap="false"` so that it stops when it reaches the end of the Carousel. Also, the left arrow becomes active when the first carousel starts.

Here's what I want to do: I want the class `class-fade` to change to `class-active` when the slide becomes active. And then change to `class-fade` when it becomes non-active again.

I hope this makes sense.

**JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/6kjnmbcb/**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>When the carousel comes to an end, change the class <strong>"class-active"</strong> to <strong>"class-fade"</strong>.
        <span class="pull-right">
                        <a class="" href="#CaseCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="class-fade"> << </i></a> 
                         &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                        <a class="" href="#CaseCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="class-active"> >> </i></a>
                    </span>
    </p>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-wrap="false" id="CaseCarousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <p>
                            Slide1 goes here
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <p>
                            Slide2 goes here
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <p>
                            Slide3 goes here
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <p>
                            Slide4 goes here
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <p>
                            Slide5 goes here
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <p>
                            Slide6 goes here
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.class-fade {
  color: grey;
}
.class-active {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Try this. I update the class-active to class-fade. and updated the css as welll. 
Try on: https://jsfiddle.net/6kjnmbcb/2/

Comment: I'm sorry but that's far from it. I actually want to change the class using JS so that users know that the button is `disabled` when there's no slide to click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `slide.bs.carousel` event described in [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events)

```
$('#CaseCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  var controls = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
  if (e.direction === 'left') {
    controls[0].className = 'controls class-active';
  }
  if (e.direction === 'right') {
    controls[1].className = 'controls class-active'
  }

  var inner = document.querySelector('.carousel-inner');
  if (e.relatedTarget == inner.lastElementChild) {
    controls[1].className = 'controls class-fade'
  }
  if (e.relatedTarget == inner.firstElementChild) {
    controls[0].className = 'controls class-fade'
  }
})
```

There is a full solution

https://jsfiddle.net/oeraa2kL/2/

Comment: Appreciate the help. Thank you so much!

Comment: Any idea how to do it for multiple carousels on the same page? It's not working when I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/177eLsmh/

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the `slide.bs.carousel` event :

Take a look at this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/BaobabCoder/7756yuzb/1/

```
$(document).on('slide.bs.carousel', '.carousel', function(e) {
    var slidesLength = $(this).find('.item').length;
    var slideFrom = $(this).find('.active').index();
    var slideTo = $(e.relatedTarget).index();
    if(slideFrom === 0 || slideTo === 0) {
        $('a[href="#CaseCarousel"][data-slide="prev"] i:eq(0)').toggleClass('class-fade');
      $('a[href="#CaseCarousel"][data-slide="prev"] i:eq(0)').toggleClass('class-active');
    }
    else if(slideFrom === slidesLength || slideTo === slidesLength) {
        $('a[href="#CaseCarousel"][data-slide="next"] i:eq(0)').toggleClass('class-fade')
      $('a[href="#CaseCarousel"][data-slide="next"] i:eq(0)').toggleClass('class-active');
    }
});
```